# Wordpress multiple template for same category with different custom post type

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories, custom-post-type, archive

I have this structure for my Wordpress site :

- Custom post type 1

  - Category a

    - Term a-1
    - Term a-2
    - ...
- Custom post type 2

  - Category a (same category than CPT 1)

    - Term a-1
    - Term a-2
    - ...

I would like to have different template for "Category a" archive page and single term page depending of current post type. How can I achieve this?

In other words, I want these URLs each have their own template :

1. http://www.example.com/custom-post-type-1/category-a/
2. http://www.example.com/custom-post-type-1/category-a/generic-single-term
3. http://www.example.com/custom-post-type-2/category-a/ (same as 1 but different CPT URL)
4. http://www.example.com/custom-post-type-2/category-a/generic-single-term (same as 2 but different CPT URL)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `taxonomy.php` template file (and its derivatives) or the `category.php` template file (and its derivatives) , ( which is is only for use with the Category taxonomy ) .

If you want an archive index for some custom taxonomy, you would use `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php` template file. So, if you have  created a custom taxonomy, `my-taxonomy`, the archive index for this taxonomy would use the `taxonomy-my-taxonomy.php` template file.

If you want an archive index for some terms inside your custom taxonomy, you use `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` template file. So, if you've got a term, `my-term`, for your custom taxonomy, the archive index for this term would be `taxonomy-my-taxonomy-my-term.php`.

(Note:a single word for name of taxonomy and or terms is better I Think.)

More info on the template hierarchy [CODEX page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) and taxonomy specific [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 2 things is not covered: 
1- How could have the right permalink structure with this template hierarchy ? (see the 4 permalink inside my question below).
2- How could I have a generic template for all my single term ?

Comment: well - your question title and content was about templates - For the permalink structure just use the tag and category base , and normal custom permalink rules. if that does not work for you, it might be more complicated but did you use the  `rewrite` argument when registering the taxonomy ? If you do not know how maybe you should have a look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hierarchical-urls/)

Comment: Thank you! Using the function {add_rewrite_rule} resolve all my problems.

Comment: Also, for other have the same problem, I found a very good tutorial: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/customizing-wordpress-archives-categories-terms-taxonomies/