# Show different templates for same category shared between posts and custom post types [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, templates, categories, custom-post-type, archive

I share categories between regular posts and custom post type named `faq` by declaring `categories` as `taxonomies` in my custom post type declaration like following:

```
function init_custom_post_type() {
  $labels = array(
    'name'                => _x('FAQ', 'Post Type General Name'),
    'singular_name'       => _x('FAQ', 'Post Type Singular Name'),
    'menu_name'           => __('FAQ')
  );
  $args = array(
    'label'               => __('FAQ'),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'taxonomies'          => array('category')
  );
  register_post_type( 'faq', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'init_custom_post_type', 2 );
```

I would like to have 2 different archive pages (2  different templates) based on the post type like this:

- for regular posts: permalinks like: https://example.com/category-a displaying regular posts with the category `category-a`
- for `faq` custom post types: permalinks like: https://example.com/faq/category-a displaying only custom post types with the category `category-a`

How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

I know this is very similar to [Wordpress multiple template for same category with different custom post type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32875274/6481285) but unfortunately I am unable to solve my issue with its answer.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this? I've run into the same problem myself now

Comment: @robobobobo Unfortunately I haven't. In the end I haven't created any archive templates for the custom post type category and I just display custom post types ordered by categories in a regular page template.